# embeding youtube video to content in wysiwyg editor

Tags: video, youtube, embed, wysiwyg

i have an editor that is basic microsoft actions: "createlink" "bold" etc.
i made page to handle the youtube embeding and it works fine on the website.
but in the editor all i can see is the rectangle of the video with nothing in it.

the editor is an iframe editable that get the content from another page - if i load that page the youtube is there but inside the editor - is not working.

did anybody got that somewhen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have add a page that get the youtube link and replace the url to the param tamplate